# how Is the similar use to isActive in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13

im tryin to use isActive in next 13 but with the actualizacion of app router i dont know how to use it please help :S

```
 <Link href={`/Pages/${link.name}`} key={link.name} onClick={() => {}}
                  className={ isActive ? activeLink : normalLink }>
                  {link.icon}
                  <span className='capitalize'>
                    {link.name} 
                  </span>
                </Link>
```

i'm trying to use the correct syntax for this with next 13 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To archive this you can use usePathname to get the path and then check if is te same in your link. Check documentation here -> [usePathname](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-pathname)

Not sure how is structured your code but probably you can do something like

```
'use client'

import { usePathname } from 'next/navigation'
 
export default function ExampleClientComponent() {
  const pathname = usePathname()
  return  <Link href={`/Pages/${link.name}`} key={link.name} onClick={() => {}}
              className={ pathname === '/link.name' ? activeLink : normalLink }>
              {link.icon}
              <span className='capitalize'>
                {link.name} 
              </span>
            </Link>
}
```